# Magento 1.9.X: how can I run magento on docker-compose?

Tags: magento-1.9, installation, server-setup, docker

how can I run magento 1 on docker-compose?
What configuration must contain docker-compose.yml file if I need want to use PHP-7.2, MySQL and Nginx?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prepare your docker environment for magento 2 you can follow the following steps:

[Environment docker magento 2](https://github.com/aissyass/magento2-docker)

Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

- Apache/2.4.29
- Webmin 1.920
- Composer 1.8.6
- Git 2.17.1

Comment: Thanks, it helped a lot !